# Search and Replace in file gives access violation

Tags: c

I'm trying to search and replace a string in a file but it gives access violation. What am i doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
BOOL SearchAndReplace(const char *destFileName, const char *srcString, const char *newString)
{
    FILE *ostream = fopen(destFileName, "r+");
    if (ostream == 0) return false;
    int f=0,n=0;
    char st[30];
    while(!feof(ostream))
    {
        fscanf(ostream,"%s",st);
        if(strcmp(st,srcString)==0)
        {
            fprintf(ostream,"%s",newString);
        }
    }
    fclose(ostream);
    return true;
}

SearchAndReplace("file.txt", "en", "tr");
```

Comment: Your C++ code looks like C.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? It'd be a lot easier to solve this once you know which statement causes the access violation.

Comment: the feof() function is not asserted true until AFTER trying to read past the end of the file,  (the main reason it should not be used as a loop control)  the result is the code will try to perform the fscanf when already at EOF.  The code fails to check the returned value from fscanf, so does not know when it fails.  after reading from the file, the file pointer is advanced to the end of the read,   the following write will not overlay the area just read from, but some point (I think at the end of the file).  using ftell() and fseek() would be needed to overlay the area read from

Comment: the fscanf uses an unlimited read size.,  what is really needed is more of a state machine that reads the file byte by byte with the state transitions being driven by the srcString parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
char st[30];
while(!feof(ostream))
{
    fscanf(ostream,"%s",st);
```

You cannot ask fscanf to read a string into such a small buffer, unless you know the string is **always** smaller than the buffer. Most likely you are encountering a larger-than-30-char string.

Allocate a larger buffer, or use some modern C++ construct, like ifstream >> string.

Also, the code above will remove whitespace. fscanf will not return the whitespace on %s.

Lastly, it will only replace exact match, surrounded by whitespace. So, replacing "foo" into "bar" in a string like "blah'foo'blah" will not work, since fscanf will not separate words at "'" (or at any other non-whitespace character)

Comment: Thanks, i changed it to 2048. It didn't give access violation error, however, it didn't replaced the string

Comment: Well, it does replace allright, just not necessarily at the right place. You'll need to test and debug a bit now that your crash is gone. For example, "123 foo 456" replacing 'foo' in 'bar', yields "123 foobar6" for me.

Comment: This is a **c** question.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the error you can limit `scanf()` to read just as many characters as your array can hold, for that use this

```
fscanf("%29s\n", st);
       /* ^ your array has room for 30, 29 characters + '\0' */
```

also, `feof()` wont return true until a read is attempted past the end of the file, so you would need one extra iteration for `feof()` to return true, and in that extra iteration, the last value at `st` will be repeated so if it matches the search string it will be printed twice, a fix would be to simple check if `fscanf()` did read a string.

```
BOOL SearchAndReplace(const char *destFileName, const char *srcString, const char *newString)
{
    int   f = 0;
    int   n = 0;
    char  st[30];
    FILE *ostream;

    ostream = fopen(destFileName, "r+");
    if (ostream == 0)
        return false;
    while (fscanf(ostream, "%29s", st) == 1)
    {
        if (strcmp(st, srcString) == 0)
            fprintf(ostream, "%s", newString);
    }
    fclose(ostream);

    return true;
}
```

and one last thing, your code wont replace the occurrences, but that's another problem.

This answer addresses your problem, but you nead a very different approach to read that file, specially if you intend to parse the file content.

Comment: Yeah, i fixed the address problem but as you said it wont replace the occurences. I changed strcmp to strstr, but still not working

Comment: @AhmetSahbaz It's not the comparison, it's the way you try to write to the file, doing it that way is not impossible but it's difficult to get it right, then depending on your requirements I would suggest opening a new file writing the modified data into it and then renaming it to the previous file name.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little bit and ran, it worked fine for me. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool SearchAndReplace(const char *destFileName, const char *srcString, const char *newString)
{
    FILE *ostream = fopen(destFileName, "r+");
    if (ostream == 0) return false;
    int f = 0, n = 0;
    char st[30];
    while (!feof(ostream))
    {
        fscanf(ostream, "%s", st);
        if (strcmp(st, srcString) == 0)
        {
            fprintf(ostream, "%s", newString);
        }
    }
    fclose(ostream);
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    bool found = SearchAndReplace("example.txt", "en", "tr");
    if (found){
        cout << "found";
    } else {
        cout << "not found";
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I am suspecting that you are running your program will lesser priveleges...

Please **run your program as administrator** and check if it still gives error.

Comment: put this text in your question. it will improve your question. :)

Answer (score -1):

I see you fixed your access error by increasing your buffer size, but now you are wondering why the file is not being updated. The problem is you need to rewind the stream before writing.

```
char* replace(char* line, char* search_pat, char* repl_pat) {
    char* ma = strstr(line, search_pat);
    if (ma == NULL)
        return NULL;
    memcpy(ma, repl_pat, strlen(repl_pat));
    return line;
    }

BOOL SearchAndReplace(const char *destFileName, const char *srcString, const char *newString)
{
    FILE *ostream = fopen(destFileName, "r+");
    if (ostream == 0) return false;
    int f=0,n=0;
    long pos;
    char st[64*1024]; /* make sure it's big enough */
    while(!feof(ostream))
    {
        pos = ftell(ostream);        /* save position before read */
        fscanf(ostream,"%s",st);
        char* newline = replace(st, srcString, newString);
        if (newline != NULL) {
            fseek(ostream, pos, 0);  /* rewind to where read from */
            fprintf(ostream,"%s",newString);
        }
    }
    fclose(ostream);
    return true;
}

SearchAndReplace("file.txt", "\"en\"", "\"tr\"");
```

*NOTE*: Your code assumes the `newString` is the EXACT same length as the `srcString`. If they are not, this code will not work. Consider instead creating a new file, then delete the original and rename your output to input.

Comment: I think the problem is your string compare operation `strcmp()`. It will only match lines that are exactly the string you are searching for (`en` in the example you shared). I could not find this string in your sample `file.txt`, but based on how it was formatted, I suspect you do not have a line that only has exactly that line. You will need to re-write the string search to match and replace a part of aline in that case.

Comment: fyi -- I edited the code to demonstrate how you would match and replace a partial section of a line. NOTE: I also changes the `srcString` and `newString` to match your `file.txt`.